# Python Pandas you are trying to merge an int and object

Tags: python, pandas, string, integer

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("koko.csv", sep=";", header=0)

df1['Hour'] = df1['Hour'].astype(str)


df2 = pd.read_csv("wowwo", sep=";", header=0)

df2['Hour'] = df2['Hour'].astype(str)

df3 = df1.join(df2, how='inner', on='Hour')`
```

When i use for the Astype (str) i get the following message:
You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns.

When i use for the Astype (int) i get the following message:
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'X253252352552'

how can i fix this?

Comment: does the join happen when you're not applying `astype()` ?

Comment: No it doesnt thats why i even used the astype command because without the astype command i still get the same error message:"You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns."

Comment: Try to read files with `dtype=str` as parameter of `pd.read_csv` then join dataframes.

Comment: df1 = pd.read_csv("koko.csv", sep=";", header=0, dtype='str') still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from different Thread:
"I had the same problem. The reason for why merge works on strings but join doesn't can be found in the answer by @MatthiasFripp here: link. Basically df1.join(df2) always merges via the index of df2 whereas df1.merge(df2) will merge on the column. So basically we were trying to merge based off a string and an integer, even though both columns were strings"

In my case both columns are strings, but the content of the Columns are a combination of strings and Integer. So thats why it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

It should've been `df1.merge(df2, on='Hour')`